# In Chicago Express, how important are strategies of tight share bidding and inducing others to develop railroads toward your shares?

Tags: chicago-express

Chicago Express appears to be a game with no luck in that there are no dice, no cards drawn. There are minimal random elements such as player seating. My interpretation of the game has been that in order to maximize your cash (to win the game), you generally aim to:

- buy shares as cheaply and at as sound an investment price as possible
- induce others to build/expand/upgrade rail roads that you own shares in
- build/expand/upgrade rail roads that help others as little as possible

Because shares are auctioned and dividends paid proportionately to the point value (akin to the market cap) of the railroad and the shares sold, the game seems very tightly bound to how efficiently you spend your efforts on yourself and how much you get others to dilute their efforts into your shares.  So, If I have a monopoly on a certain railroad, it sounds like I should always build/expand that one (when building and expanding), and when I see a player with only one railroad or an overwhelming interest in expanding that one railroad, I should seek to gain shares in that railroad.

Since your choices and ability to bid (and thus your ability to position your relative railroad ownership versus the other players) diminish immensely once you have no cash, it seems you have to be extremely careful about early bids and should be very willing to pass on expensive auction in order to maintain cash flow and avoid getting, well, railroaded (had to say it).

Other aspects of the game don't seem as crucial to me. Are there elements of how one expands their railroad across the board or builds extra value into their railroads' income track scores that become more prevalent, or is it more that you simply are building/expanding a certain railroad that matters rather than how you're doing it? Do other considerations such as how many potential turns remain for auction, development, or route construction matter much?

Comment: I see that there are, so far, 3 "close" votes for my question, and it'd be really helpful to hear feedback on how I can improve this question. I'm trying to give my impression of what I think may be the important strategic considerations and wondering how they stack up. One example of interesting feedback (pointed out to me outside of this site) was that  railroad route construction can be a key element as players with small share aim to hijack the development of a railroad and spend all its resources *wastefully* just to harm a player with a large share in that railroad.

Comment: I'd do the following. (A) No description of Chicago Express; people that need it can't help you. (B) Delete the strategy musings - basically from the middle of paragraph 1 to the beginning of paragraph 4. (C) Unify the three different questions you've asked (one in the title and two in the last paragraph) or ask three separate questions on the site. I think your real question may be "What strategies work well in Chicago Express?" which I think is answerable. But the question you've posted looks like it is meant to inspire a discussion, which is out of scope for the site.

Comment: Is a question as simple as "what strategies work well in ____" really acceptable? I feel like the general message in the faq and meta posts is that it is too general.

Comment: Maybe not, but then you should split this question into several specific ones. It's also possible that SE is just a bad fit for what you are looking for and you'd be better off at BoardGameGeek reading strategy articles and discussion threads.